# What is the examples of frequency (pitch) in elements of audio

Tags: musical-forms

What is the examples of frequency pitch?

Comment: Hello! It is not clear (at least to me) what you are asking... Any sound wave with a bit periodicity can be seen as having a fundamental frequency (to an extend) and perceived at the certain pitch...

Comment: ... And even non-periodic signals have measurably different amounts of energy in different frequency bands. As Tom says, can you please explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: A simple sine wave may contain only one pitch, whereas other sounds will contain many - overtones, harmonics, partials. The question isn't clear enough to answer.